# What else can the elliptic integral count?

Tags: fourier-series, elliptic-curves, combinatorics

I just read this document - [Jacobi's Four Square Theorem](http://www.math.ohio-state.edu/~econrad/Jacobi/sumofsq/sumofsq.html). It shows how to count the number of representations of a number as the sum of four squares.

I can follow the proof but currently it just appears like a brilliant coincidence, so I am wondering what else can you count with these?

Answer (score 2):

"What else can you count with these?": Solutions to the Fermat equation $x^n + y^n = z^n$.  (If this doesn't make immediate sense, I will add more material later, when I have more time.)